# Looking for the name of a sweet green drink

Tags: alcohol, drinks, food-identification

A long time ago I tasted an alcoholic drink which was green and tasted very sweet (possibly like banana, definitely not mint), and it had a long french name, something like (pesong, pisang, ...). Does anyone know the real name of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for Pisang Ambon, a banana liqeur, which is seethrough and green. It is popularly served over ice, mixed with orange juice for a Tutti Frutti kind of drink.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisang_Ambon

Comment: Woohoo! You're batting 1000 tonight!

Comment: yess :D it's this one!

Answer (score 1):

Originally, the name for the drink we call the Grasshopper was Tujague’s, named for the New Orleans bar. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: possibly not, no mint in my drink.